# The only thing I can think of that it is like - A question of English grammar

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

> Such a peculiar odor, too! I have spent hours in trying to analyze it, to find what it smelled like. 
>   It is not bad—at first, and very gentle, but quite the subtlest, most enduring odor I ever met. 
>   In this damp weather it is awful, I wake up in the night and find it hanging over me. 
>   It used to disturb me at first. I thought seriously of burning the house—to reach the smell. 
>   But now I am used to it. The only thing I can think of **that it is like is** the COLOR of the paper! A yellow smell.

From "Yellow Paper" by Charlotte Perkins Gilman (1892)

I just wonder the above sentence is grammatically correct. 
Could it be re-written as "what it is like is" ? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only thing I can think of that it is like is the COLOR of the paper!

It's correct.

1. The only thing I can think of, is the COLOR of the paper!

2 a. The only thing I can think of (that the smell is like) is the COLOR of the paper!

2 b. The only thing I can think of (that it is like) is the COLOR of the paper!

3. The only thing I can think of, that it is like, is the COLOR of the paper!
4. The only thing I can think of that it is like is the COLOR of the paper!

Does that help?